# portable packages

Tags: packages, documentation

and sorry again for my bad grammar, English is not my native idiom.

I start explaining about what I have and then what I want:

I built a format for my school so students can build up their thesis without having headache with latex environment (out of topic: wanna upload it when it's done so i can have a viewpoint of all, but dunno if put it like a question or if there's a specific link for that.).

What I want of the project is to build it portable, so the students don't have to dowload all MiKTeX, I just want the specific packages I call on my `.sty` and if possible to have them in the same folder.

Is there a way so I can migrate the specific packages so I can use them on the same folder of my .sty? Or is there a way to call packages from a diferent directory?

I'll add more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the [`snapshot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) package and [`bundledoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) to bundle together all the files needed to build your document.

Comment: i understood how to use the snapshot package but how i use the bundledoc or where do i put the instruction to call the .dep file?

Comment: @Yaren `bundledoc` is a Perl script (so you need Perl installed in your system). Once the `.dep` file was created (say, `test.dep`), you open a a terminal, move to the directory containing `test.dep` and run `bundledoc test.dep`.

Comment: @Yaren depending on your operating system you might need to change the configuration for `bundledoc`; [this document](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/support/bundledoc/bundledoc.pdf) gives the details.

Comment: thx for that! now gona try bundledoc on my proyect.